# How to release a Sequel connection when using a pool

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sidekiq, sequel

I am facing some pooling problems using the Sequel gem and Postgres.
I believe that my Sidekiq jobs aren't releasing the connections they use from the pool.

I connect to the DB when starting Sidekiq using:

```
DB = Sequel.connect(db_uri, max_connections: 20)
```

I was thinking of some Sidekiq middleware, like this:

```
module Middleware
  class SequelDisconnector
    def call(*args)
      yield
    ensure
      DB.release_active_pool_connection
    end
  end
end
```

I know there is `DB.disconnect` but that disconnects entirely from the DB right? I want to make sure my worker releases its connection while not killing any of the other workers' connections.

Is there any way to achieve this or do I have some kind of flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: Ya, the Sequel docs don't do a very good job of explaining _how_ to use the connection pool very well.  It looks like you do need to call `disconnect` to release a connection back to the pool.  I went through the gem but I'm still not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to understand that your worker is not necessarily using a single connection, but could be using many different connections, unless you are specifically doing something to limit it to a single connection via `Database#synchronize` or `Database#transaction`.

You should not need to disconnect specific connections as it is expected that connections will remain in Sequel's connection pool for later use.  Is there a reason you think the connections should be disconnected and removed from the pool?